# Where to specify path in Angular for corrct import?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular8

There is file `map-api.d.ts`

it has import:

```
import { MapProps } from "Map/map";
```

So path `Map/map` is located in the the level as file `map-api.d.ts`.

But VS says

> Cannot find module 'Map/map'.

How to configure path to this file.

if to set `./` in `import { MapProps } from "./Map/map";` it works. But hot to specify this everywhere?

Comment: There are `angular.json` files and `ng-package.json` and `tsconfig.json`

Comment: I have tried to edit tsconfig.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tsconfig.json you can specify global path:

```
"paths": {
      "@environments/*": ["environments/*"],
      "@listing/core": ["libs/core/src/index.ts"]
    }
```

and use them in every component/service like this:

```
import { environment } from '@environments/environment';
```

Comment: How to set path if I have /dir/dir1/dir2/file.ts and I need to specify path to ` /dir/import.ts`?

Comment: `@myFancyMod/*": ["dir/dir2/*"]` and import via `import {things} from '@myFancyMod/things'; `

And `things`is something defined in import.ts (or files that import.ts handles)